# How to find smallest connected label in equivalency list

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have a list of numbers stored in a standard vector. Some of the numbers are children of other numbers. Here is an example

```
3, 4
3, 5
5, 6
7, 3
8, 9
8, 1
8, 2
9, 8
```

Or as a graph:

```
1 2 3-4 5-6 7 8-9
|-------------|
  |-----------|
    |---|     
    |-------|
```

That is there are two clusters 3,4,5,6,7 and 1,2,8,9. The root number is the smallest number of a cluster. Here 3 and 1. I would like to know which algorithms I can use to extract a list like this:

```
3, 4
3, 5
3, 6
3, 7
1, 2
1, 8
1, 9
```

Comment: How are the numbers stored in that vector?

Comment: There are probably better approaches but you could create a struct named cluster, containing nodes and edges. Create a list of clusters, one cluster for each number. Add the number to the nodes and each relation to the edges. Iterate over the clusters and merge clusters with a common edge. Remove all edges that are between one cluster and the other cluster. Repeat until you removed all edges. Find the root value.

Comment: Are the numbers always 1 to N or similar? In other words, can they be used as indices?

Comment: @Nelfeal The numbers cannot always used as indices.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Currently I'm using the following data structure: `std::vector<std::vector<unsigned int>> list`. After processing, the list's size is of `N x 2`.

Comment: Is it possible that a number has no parent and no child?

Comment: @ThomasSablik There are only numbers with connections to other numbers.

Comment: You don't have a list of numbers but a list of edges.

Comment: @ThomasSablik Yes, that is true.

Answer (score 1):

An algorithm similar disjoint set union algorithm can help you:

- Initialize `N` disjoint subset, each subset has exactly one number, and root of number `i(r(i))` is `i`.
- For each edge `(u, v)`, you can assign:

```
    t = min(r(u), r(v))
    r(u) = t
    r(v) = t
```

- For each `i` with `i != r(i)`, you can write out `[r(i) - i]`.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What is `r`, `u` and `v`? What do you mean by `i (r(i))`? Can you please provide a good source for this algorithm?

Comment: @Random9. I think this refers to an algorithm known as "Union Find". I googled "union find" and several reasonable hits came up. I looked at a few and they all seem to explain it quite well. So google that and it should be clear.

Comment: `N` is the number of numbers. `r(i)` is the root of number `i`. `u` and `v` are two numbers have connect. This is wiki about Disjoint Set union algorithm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure#Union.

Comment: @dangxuanvuong98 It is worth to edit you answer and add information from comment.